# How to prove mathematically that a decrease in regularization parameter would result in a decrease in the cost function?

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose this is my cost function:
$$
J(\theta)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i-\theta^tx_i)^2 + \lambda |\theta|^2
$$
After optimizing the equation we can find an optimal $\theta^*$, such that:
$$
\theta^*=argmin_{\theta} J(\theta)
$$
My question is: How can I prove mathematically, that a decrease in $\lambda$ would result in a decrease for the overall $J(\theta^*)$?

Comment: $|\theta|^2$ is positive. Adding something positive to anything increases that anything. By adjusting $\lambda$ you are adjusting how much that *anything* is increased. Does that help?

Comment: By "overall" do you mean the *infimum* of $J(\theta)$?

Comment: @IgorF. Sorry just edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: @whuber Yes. Just edited my question so it is clearer.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those cases where a grand generalization gives a simple demonstration and has important applications.

Suppose, then, that $\Theta$ is any nonempty set, $g,f:\Theta\to\mathbb R$ are functions, $f$ is bounded below, and $g(\theta)\ge 0$ for all $\theta\in\Theta.$  For any number $\lambda$ define

$$\theta^{*}(\lambda) = \inf_{\theta\in\Theta} \left(f(\theta) + \lambda g(\theta)\right).$$

I claim that $\theta^{*}$ is an increasing function at $0;$ that is, for all $\lambda \ge 0,$ $\theta^{*}(\lambda)\ge \theta^{*}(0).$

**Proof**  Suppose not. Fix $\lambda\ge 0$ and write $$\epsilon = \theta^{*}(0) - \theta^{*}(\lambda) \gt 0.$$ From the definition of the infimum there exists $\theta_0$ for which $f(\theta_0) + \lambda g(\theta_0)$ is no greater than $\theta^{*}(\lambda) + \epsilon/2.$  Because $\lambda$ and $g(\theta_0)$ are nonnegative (by assumption), compute

$$f(\theta_0) \le f(\theta_0) + \lambda g(\theta_0) \le \theta^{*}(\lambda) + \epsilon/2 \lt \theta^{*}(\lambda) + \epsilon \lt \theta^{*}(0)$$

giving $f(\theta_0) \lt \theta^{*}(0).$

**This is a contradiction,** because (by definition) for *every* $\theta_0\in\Theta,$ $f(\theta_0) \ge \theta^{*}(0),$ *QED.*

---

Given $(x_i),$ $(y_i),$, $\Theta\subset\mathbb{R}^N,$ and *any* number $\lambda_1,$ take

$$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \theta^\prime x_i)^2 + \lambda_1|\theta|^2$$

and

$$g(\theta) = |\theta|^2 \ge 0$$

for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^N.$

**Applying the claim proves a weak version of the result in the question:** increasing $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_2 = \lambda_1 + \lambda$ cannot decrease $f.$

**This is the best possible general result,** because there are cases where no decrease is possible.  Any situation where $\Theta$ has a single element $\theta$ and $g(\theta)=0$ can serve as an example.

Comment: +1.  I love a good proof.

Comment: Thanks very much! That is a very detailed proof!

Answer (score 1):

The cost $J$ is being minimised. If for a a particular $\lambda_a$ you minimize the cost $J_a$ with a particular $\theta_a$ then that same $\theta_a$ for a different lower $\lambda_b$ should result in a lower cost $J$ and the minimized $J_b$ for that different lower $\lambda_b$ should be at least lower (because otherwise it would not be an optimum).

---

Let the cost be the function $J(\theta, \lambda)$. And let $\theta_a$ be the estimate/argmin/optimum for $\lambda_a$, let $\theta_b$ be the estimate/argmin/optimum for $\lambda_b$.

Then
$$J(\theta_a, \lambda_b) < J(\theta_a,\lambda_a)$$

if $$\lambda_b < \lambda_a$$

and if

$$|\theta_a| > 0$$
(the negation of the latter case $|\theta_a| = 0$ is the trivial case in which we would also have $J=0$ and there would not be anything to decrease)

So the solution $\theta_a$ for $\lambda_b$ gives at least a lower value $J$. Then when we minimize $J$ to end up with a $\theta_b$ we must have at least

$$\rlap{\overbrace{\phantom{J(\theta_b,\lambda_b) \leq J(\theta_a, \lambda_b)}}^{\substack{\text{The solution with $\theta_b$}\\\text{must be better than or the same as}\\\text{the solution with $\theta_a$}}}} J(\theta_b,\lambda_b) \leq \underbrace{J(\theta_a, \lambda_b) < J(\theta_a,\lambda_a)}_{\substack{\text{With the same $\theta_a$}\\\text{and $\lambda_b < \lambda_a$}\\\text{the cost will be lower}}} $$

Comment: You need to be a little careful.  I posted an answer showing what kind of care is required to be fully correct.

Comment: You assume optima exist.  They do not need to--and such situations occur in practice, so we need to pay attention to them.

Comment: Another little problem is exemplified by the case $y_i=0$ for all $i,$ even when the optima do exist (assuming $0$ is a possible value of $\theta$): now your strict inequality at the end is always false, because $\theta=0$ is an optimum for any $\lambda \ge 0.$

Comment: No, I mean it doesn't exist, due perhaps to constraints on $\theta.$  Suppose the user requires that at all components of $\theta$ be strictly positive, for instance, but without that restriction the optimal $\theta$ would have negative components.

Comment: The example that you mention is the trivial case when we also have $J = 0$. Are there any other cases where it doesn't work? (So my first inequality fails when $\theta_a=0$).

Comment: I believe so: consider collinear explanatory variables.

Comment: I do not see how the non-negative constraint changes my reasoning.

Comment: You come to a general conclusion that is false in specific instances: that proves there's something the matter with your demonstration.

Comment: @whuber You say plural instances, but I believe that is incorrect, There is only a single instance, which is when $\vert \theta \vert = 0$ (in which case we also have $J=0$ and there is nothing to improve). I have corrected this in the text. So my statement $J(\theta_a, \lambda_b) < J(\theta_a,\lambda_a)$ was not generally correct. But with a simple restriction, excluding the trivial case, $\vert \theta \vert = 0$ , the statement holds.

Comment: In the case of $\vert \theta \vert = 0$, we would indeed get the weaker result, but this weak result is only the case for that very limited case.

$$\rlap{\overbrace{\phantom{J(\theta_b,\lambda_b) \leq J(\theta_a, \lambda_b)}}^{\substack{\text{The solution with $\theta_b$}\\\text{must be better than or the same as}\\\text{the solution with $\theta_a$}}}} J(\theta_b,\lambda_b) \leq \underbrace{J(\theta_a, \lambda_b) \leq J(\theta_a,\lambda_a)}_{\substack{\text{With the same $\theta_a$}\\\text{and $\lambda_b < \lambda_a$}\\\text{the cost will be lower}}} $$